# Can't undo or redo actions that add a row to a NSOutlineView

Tags: delete-row, nsoutlineview, undo-redo

Most of my undo/redo actions have stopped working.  I've written a simple example.

**aNewNoteFor**
successfully adds an OutlineItem to its sibling's parent's children and inserts it into the OutlineView row following its sibling.

**deleteAChild**:
is supposed to remove the row and delete it from its parent's children.

But neither undo or redo are enabled.

```
- (void)aNewNoteFor:(OutlineItem*) sibling
{
    //Ignore note. it's unimportant
    Note* note = [self.document makeDraft:YES];
    OutlineItem* newChild = [[OutlineItem alloc]initWithNote:note];
    NSInteger index = [sibling.parent.children indexOfObject:sibling] +1;
    [sibling.parent.children insertObject:newChild atIndex:index];
    newChild.parent = sibling.parent;
    [_document updateChangeCount:NSChangeDone];
    [_outlineOutlet reloadData];
    [_undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(deleteAChild:) object:newChild];
}

-(void)deleteAChild: (OutlineItem*)child
{
    OutlineItem* parent = child.parent;
    [parent.children removeObject:child];
    [_outlineOutlet reloadData];
    [_undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(aNewNoteFor:) object:parent];
}
''''
```

Comment: Maybe the menu items and your code don't use the same undo manager. Is the app document based? Which class is `self` in the code you posted? How is `_undoManager` created?

Comment: Thanks for responding Wileke.  Yes it is document-based.  Self is an NSViewController. It is declared in a viewController scene within main.storyboard.  _undoManager is defined in the viewController as    _undoManager = [self.view.window undoManager];

Comment: Try `_undoManager = _document.undoManager;`.

Comment: I tried it.  _undoManager is nil.  Have I somehow killed the _document.undoManager?

Comment: After I moved you suggestion, undo/redo work.  Thanks, Willeke.